# yotpo reviews not working in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I need to add rich snippets in a big-commerce store including the ratings/reviews of the products and for generating reviews, I am using yotpo.

I have added the code for the rich snippets in the big-commerce store and everything is in order but still when I test it using google testing tool (http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) it does not show the reviews of the products.

For example, this is a link of a product with ratings

http://drillsandcutters.com/1-2-hss-split-point-black-and-gold-killer-force-kfd-jobber-length-drill-bit/

In the bigcommerce store it shows the ratings but in the GOOGLE Search it does not, not in the testing tool also

I have also checked the source code of the above products page and have seen that the "ratingValue" and "ratingCount" =  0.

Regards,
Inzamam Tahir

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by moving/copying your reviews from Yotpo to Bigcommerce' product review system.

Your problem is that Yotpo stores and manages the reviews and injects them onto your product page via javascript. Google (mostly) ignores javascript on the page and thus is not seeing the reviews that are not truly part of the page.

So, you are left with leaving them on Yotpo and getting more reviews, moving them all back into Bigcommerce, or trying to mirror the Yotpo reviews in Bigcommerce.

Comment: Hi, thanks for stopping by and  trying to help me out.....but I have found out that Yotpo do not support BigCommerce yet as shown in this image http://i.imgur.com/wPK40Rr.png taken from http://blog.yotpo.com/2013/05/16/introducing-google-rich-snippet-support-for-yotpo-reviews/ so, I think that it won't work for me....Can you please suggest some other review system for BigCommerce besides its own ???

Comment: Yotpo actually does have a Bigcommerce app. While there are other 3rd party plugins/services, the issue is the same. The only way the reviews will be part of the source code (and not added in via javascript) is to use the Bigcommerce reviews. My answer applies regardless of which 3rd party service you are using.